# Adobe Increment Stamp

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I have a custom stamp that increase a number or letter like: 1,2,3 or A, B, C
I want to upgrade the code of the stamp for increase like this: A1, A2, A3 or B1, B2, B3

how can i do this?

this is the code:

```
if (event.source.forReal && event.source.stampName == "#qT1ZWzIPGprVS_jnLHz-tB")
    {
        if ("aincState" in event.source.source.info)
            {
                if (!isNaN(event.source.source.info.aincState))
                    {
                        event.source.source.info.aincState = String(Number(event.source.source.info.aincState)+1);
                    }
                else if (event.source.source.info.aincState.length == 1)
                    {
                        var ascii = event.source.source.info.aincState.charCodeAt(0);
                        if ((ascii >= 65 && ascii < 90) || (ascii >= 97 && ascii < 122))
                            {
                                event.source.source.info.aincState = String.fromCharCode(ascii+1)
                            }
                        else if (ascii == 122)
                            {
                                event.source.source.info.aincState = "a";
                            } 
                        else
                            event.source.source.info.aincState = "A";
                    }
                else
                    {
                        event.source.source.info.aincState = "A";
                    }
            }
        else
        {
            event.source.source.info.aincState = app.response("Enter number or letter:", "Initialize State");
        }
    event.value = event.source.source.info.aincState;
}
```

[Here is a demonstration.](https://gifyu.com/image/S9dVu)

Comment: else else is quite uncommon ...

Comment: so you put A then it will be A1 A2 A3, if it B then B1 B2 B3, like that?